# what's the difference between factorial=factorial *i, if the line is before or after the printf?

Tags: c, factorial

Only the second code is good,but i don't understand why!

Just tell me what is the difference between line with factorial if it is before or after the printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int numar;
    printf("introdu un numar:");
    scanf("%d",&numar);

    int factorial = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= numar; i++) {
        printf("%d * %d =%d\n" , factorial,i,factorial*i);
        factorial = factorial * i;
    }
}
```

second code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int numar;
    printf("introdu un numar:");
    scanf("%d",&numar);

    int factorial = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= numar; i++) {
        factorial = factorial * i;
        printf("%d * %d = %d\n", factorial, i, factorial*i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to print what the factorial is at each iteration?

Comment: i don't understand your question

Comment: Translation: De ce vrei sa listezi valoarea la fiecare iteratie?

Comment: i want to test because i want to see the result

Comment: the difference is that the first code prints the correct value and the second does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second code is actually wrong. It gives me 5! = 600, but that's not right. The first code shows 120 as it should, and everything looks nice.

The reason the first is right is because it shows the current value staged to multiply with the next number, and showing the resultant calculation before you actually do it. The second is wrong because it does the calculation, and does it correctly, but then displays the calculation **done over again**...so you will get the right factorial, but you won't `printf` the right values.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the first sample of your code should display the correct values. Because in the second one, the value displayed is multiplied by the index i twice (even though the value of factorial doesn't change the second time you multiply it).

Consider this example - when i is 3 and factorial is 2:

- First code will print "2*3 = 6", then will multiply factorial by 3, so at the end of the iteration factorial is 6.
- Second code will multiply factorial by 3, so now factorial is 6. Then it will print "6*3 = 18" - the operation is not correct for factorials, even though the result is. There is no number which has its factorial equal to 18. However, factorial still holds the value 6. It's just the printed operation that is incorrect.